# How to embed image to a Windows shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, shortcuts, icons

How can I add my custom image to a shortcut to a URL, so that if I move that shortcut to another system, the icon stays the same?

I tried with copying my shortcut icon with image also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change a shortcut's icon:

1. Right click the shortcut and click Properties.
2. Click the Change Icon button.
3. Select the icon by clicking Browse and navigating to the file that contains the icon. Windows can use icons that are embedded in `.exe`, `.dll`, and `.ico` files.

   [image]

---

In order for the shortcut to be moved to another system and for the icon to still work, you must place the source of the icon in the same location on the destination computer.

For instance, if I create a shortcut with an icon that is located at `C:\IconFile`, I must copy the icon to `C:\IconFile` on the other computer before copying the shortcut.